# 0-to-1 transition point for a given Address

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find the 0-to-1 transition point for a given Address in the table.
The table looks like this
[Table History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6ENq.png)

[The expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJ34K.png)

It's a value of 1 that occurs after 0 for each addres, I must do it in one questionm and I have no idea how to do it in one question.

For any help thank you very much!

Comment: Try to add table structure with sample data and expected result in here rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I managed to solve it this way:

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM ( SELECT idHistory, DateTime, Address ,isBusy, (isBusy > LAG(isBusy) OVER (PARTITION 
       BY Address ORDER BY DateTime ASC)) as Zajety
       FROM History WHERE Address IN(772,669,720,721) ORDER BY Zajety) AS History1
WHERE History1.Zajety = 1;`